# Drupal xmlrpc user.login suddenly fails

Tags: drupal, xml-rpc

I am accessing a Drupal Views feed through xmlrpc. The script has worked in the past and my goal today was solely to access another feed. In theory, there was nothing to do except to change the name of the feed.  The endpoint had not changed, my domain had not changed, I can log in to the remote site so my user credentials there are valid.

I am scratching my head as to what may have changed. Is there an obvious question that I have missed?  What could have changed on the Drupal end that I should be taking into account?

I can also get a session id for an anonymous user okay.

The failure comes during the complicate authentication (that has worked in the past).

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ah... if anyone else has the same problem, as I worked through my script, printing out its effect at each line, I came across a comment I had made when I wrote it.

Make sure the client and the remote are on the same time, preferably the time provided by www.time.is.

My PC was running a minute slow.  The detafult Resynchronise on Windows 7 runs at 1am on a Sunday. Change that to a more sensible time.

And for an immediate fix, change the PC time to within a few seconds of www.time.is.

That was the problem.  Authenticated login uses a time stamp. It the remote server regards your time as too inaccurate, it will reject your login.  Make sure the client is running with an accurate clock.